# ¿Ayuda Problema Uva online Judge 12150 - Pole Position Wrong Answer?

Tags: java

Me sale wrong answerd y no sé por qué si mi respuesta es idéntica a la de udebug. El problema tiene este ID (12150 - Pole Position) este es mi codigo si alguien lo resolvio ayuda el problemas se llama Pole Position con id 12150.

Uva Online judge es una plataforma para subir código de problemas, un juez Virtual que acepta o rechaza el problema enviado como Virtual Judge o Code Forces no me sale un error en el código.

El problema es que al subir el código a uva el juez inica que la respuesta es incorrecta, talvez no entendí bien el problema pero igual no tengo muchos casos de prueba para este este es el link del problema:

https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3302

si ejecutan el codigo con los casos de prueba del problema dara la salida correcta pero el juez no me lo acepta y no logro encontrar el porque esa es mi duda gracias.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
        Par par;
        ArrayList<Par> positions;
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> inicuad;
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder ans;
        StringBuilder ansr = new StringBuilder();
        int testCase, i, card, pos, key;
        String line;
        while((testCase=read.nextInt()) != 0){
            ans = new StringBuilder();
            inicuad = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
            positions = new ArrayList<Par>();
            for(i=0; i<testCase; i++){
                card = read.nextInt();
                pos = read.nextInt();
                par = new Par(card, pos);
                positions.add(par);
            }
            for (int j=0;j<positions.size() ;j++ ) {
                key = positions.get(j).val2 + j;
                if(inicuad.containsKey(key) || key<0 || key > testCase){
                    inicuad = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
                    inicuad.put(0, -1);
                    break;
                }else{
                    inicuad.put(key, positions.get(j).val1);
                }
            }
            for(int r : inicuad.keySet()){
                ans.append(inicuad.get(r)+" ");
            }
            line = ans.toString();
            line = line.trim();
            ansr.append(line+"\n");
        }
        System.out.print(ansr.toString());
    }

    static class Par{
        int val1, val2;
        Par(int val1, int val2){
            this.val1 = val1;
            this.val2 = val2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor el problema? En tu código no aparece ningún aviso de error, y no toda la gente sabe que es eso de UVA Online Judge...

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione el juez no me aceptaba por esto:
key > testCase //esta mal ya que no debe ser solo > sino debe ser key >= testCase
Gracias :D